# Mysql listens to all yet remote connections not possible

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I am running this command on Centos

`netstat -an|grep 3306 | grep LISTEN`

and it gives me

`tcp       0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                  0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

yet when I try to connect to the server remotely, I can't.

My

`/sbin/iptables -L -v -n`

looks like -

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1347 packets, 211K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                              
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                        tcp dpt:3306

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                              

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1346 packets, 591K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I am using mysql 5.1.

Comment: How did you try to connect remotely? Did you try telnet?

Comment: I have the public ip and the inet address. I used inet address in `$con=mysqli_connect("inet","user","password","foo");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_close($con);`

Comment: So what's the output of mysqli_connect_error()?

Comment: Cannot connect to the database.I also tried with a  desktop client and gives 10060 error,cannot connect.

Comment: If you had tried "telnet ip-address 3306" you probably would have seen that you can in fact connect. 10060 is generally a permission denied, see http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,49742,239961 for details. basically you need to GRANT permissions for that user and password to access the database _from that IP address_.

Comment: I can telnet my inet address from within the server but not out when i use putty.